# Turn on / turn off Push Notification on Ionic 3 using cordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: angular, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I tried doing it with unregister method and then get a new token. I have also tried with subscribe / unsubscribe method, and both ways do not work correctly for me.

Anyone has any suggestions to implement turn off and turn on the notifications, I spent more than 10 hours trying different ways.

I am using the last version (cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.25)

Thanks for you support!

Answer (score 1):

We have integrated a solution easy:

Added an end point /api/mute_push_notification, This one remove/add the token from our database.
On the app we have toggle that turns it on and off.
Maybe, This is just a workaround.
What do you think ?

Thanks for your support.